# What is the name of this test for the probability of differences between lists and is it valid?

Tags: probability, ranking, combinatorics, rating

And are there any better methods?

In a 1969 book about investing, the author Burton P. Fabricand describes a method for assessing the effectiveness of a stock picker. Ask the picker to provide a list of n stocks that they think will be good investments, and another list of another n stocks that they think will be bad investments. (Nothing appears in both lists - the two lists are completely different). After some time, say a year, rank the first list in order of price growth, and then rank the second list in order of price growth. The two lists are kept separate. Then place the two lists side by side. Go down the rows and add up how many times that the growth in the first list is higher than the growth in the second list for items that are both on the same row, only. Call this k.

The probability of getting a score of k by chance is (n+1-k)/(n+1).

The author says this method comes from combinatorial analysis and "goes under the name of ballot problems", but I have not been able to find out anything more about it. The author has a PhD in physics.

Edit: I see that the formula is identical to that in the "Variant:ties allowed" section of the "Bertrand's ballot theorem" Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed

So my question now is, is this a valid way of estimating the probability of differences between lists, and are there any better ones?

Another edit: The method is similar to that of comparing two cumulative distributions, as used in the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and the Kuiper test. It gives a probability directly without needing to look up a table.

Comment: Sounds like the [Mann-Whitney U test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) to me, except that the p-value is not computed from the normal distribution.